# Convert text file to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have a text file (record.txt) with the contents like this:

```
12-34,Doe,John:Art101,98:History201,56
56-78,Smith,Bob,bobsmith@email.com:Calculus300,45:Economics214,78:ECE415,84
```

The email field is optional so it may or may not be included for each person.

This is how the JSON format should look like:

```
[{
    "id": "12-34", "lastname": "Doe", "firstname": "John",
    "classes":[{
        "classname":"Art101", "grade":"98"},{
        "classname":"History201","grade":"56"}]
 },
 {
    "id": "56-78", "lastname": "Smith", "firstname": "Bob", 
    "email":"bobsmith@email.com,
    "classes":[{
        "classname":"Calculus300", "grade":"45"},{
        "classname":"Economics214","grade":"78"},
        "classname":"ECE415", "grade":"84"}]
 }]
```

I am new to Python and JSON so I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to convert the contents in such a way where the email can be an optional field and how to serialize the classes for each person as well. I was unable to convert the data into JSON after multiple attempts.

Any suggestions or advice on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: get line and first split on `:` and next every element split on `,`. You can use `len()` to check if first part has 3 or 4 elements - if 4 then there is email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get line and first split on `:` and next every element split on `,`. You can use `len()` to check if first part has 3 or 4 elements - if 4 then there is email.

```
import json

text = '''12-34,Doe,John:Art101,98:History201,56
56-78,Smith,Bob,bobsmith@email.com:Calculus300,45:Economics214,78:ECE415,84'''

all_data = []

for line in text.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    parts = line.split(':')

    data = parts[0].split(',')
    classes = parts[1:]

    item = {
        'id': data[0],
        'lastname': data[1],
        'firstname': data[2],
        'classes': [],
    }

    if len(data) > 3:
        item['email'] = data[3]

    for class_ in classes:
        name, grade = class_.split(',')
        item['classes'].append({'classname': name, 'grade': grade})

    all_data.append(item)

print(json.dumps(all_data, indent=2))
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12-34",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "firstname": "John",
    "classes": [
      {
        "classname": "Art101",
        "grade": "98"
      },
      {
        "classname": "History201",
        "grade": "56"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "56-78",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "firstname": "Bob",
    "classes": [
      {
        "classname": "Calculus300",
        "grade": "45"
      },
      {
        "classname": "Economics214",
        "grade": "78"
      },
      {
        "classname": "ECE415",
        "grade": "84"
      }
    ],
    "email": "bobsmith@email.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply but what if `"lastname" :data[1]` gives me a "list index out of range" error

Comment: then first you could use `print()` to check what you have in line. And next you can add `try/except` to catch error and skip it. Or use `if len(data) > 1:` to check if index exists. BTW: you can also use `if line.strip():` to run code only when line is not empty.

Comment: `if len(data)>1:` worked perfectly! I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by `if  line.strip():`

Comment: `line.strip()` removes spaces, tabs, enters - so you get only chars in row, or empty string if there is no other chars. And empty string gives `False` when you check `if line.strip():`. Not empty string gives `True` when you check `if line.strip():` - it is common method to check if line/string is not empty. BTW: you can also check `print( bool(line.strip()) )` to see it. OR `print( bool(""), bool("text") )`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you tried.
Read each line, split based on colon (:).
Split the 0th index with (,) if length is 4 process for email. Else ignore.

Hope this is clear